# Customize react-select CreatableSelect components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

For the default `Select` component of `react-select`, you can customize some elements of the component using the prop `components`, like so:

```js
import Select from 'react-select'

<Select components={{ Menu: () => <>/* some custom menu component */</> }}
```

Is this possible for the `CreatableSelect` component? I can't find it anywhere on the [docs](https://react-select.com/creatable).

Comment: have you found a way to style CreatableSelect individual components?